# Outlook 2013 how to enable autocomplete of date

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

Is there a way to configure Outlook 2013 to autocomplete dates, e.g., Start typing "sept" ... returns September instead of September, 22, 2014?

This feature was available in my earlier version of Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

In my outlook, **if I begin to type "Septe", I get the autocomplete option for just the month**, "September", when I hit enter.

If I finish typing "September ", the autocomplete suggestion **becomes the current date**:   ("September 22, 2014").

So perhaps the answer is simply: do not type the full word "September"

Answer (score 0):

Auto-complete list will be built as you send email using outlook client.. If it is a brand new setup, there is no auto-complete unless you backup old auto-complete from your old outlook....
Following are the steps to check it:
**File > Options > Mail**:
[Checked] Use Auto-complete List to suggest names when typing in the To, CC, and Bcc lines

You can also Clear the Previous Cache, by clicking the button next to it.